# .ajax() post to callback file does not recognize php define constant

Tags: php, json, jquery

When using the code below I am having trouble setting the right location. Somehow in the callback file the php constant is not recognised, thus the rest of the code is not functioning.

snippet from html:

```
<a href="#" class="selectLocation" id="ABC">
```

snippet from .js

```
var locationID;

    $(".selectLocation").click(function(){
    locationID = this.id;
    setLocation();
    });

function setLocation() {
    $.ajax({
        data: {location: locationID},
        success: function (data) {
        // do something
        };
    });
  };

// DEFAULT AJAX SETUP
$(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        type: "POST",
        url: "dir/callback.php",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: "false",
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                console.log('No connecting.\n Verify Network.');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 400) {
                console.log('Bad Request. [400]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                console.log('Requested page not found. [404]');
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');
            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
                console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.');
            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                console.log('Time out error.');
            } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                console.log('Ajax request aborted.');
            } else {
                console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);
            };
        }
    });
```

snippet from callback.php:

```
    <?php
    header("content-type:application/json");
    session_start();
    require_once ('config.php');
...

    $connect->setLocation($_POST['location']);
```

the $_POST['location']; will send ABC to the rest of my code instead of the right value defined below.

snippet from config.php:

```
define('ABC', 'some location');
```

While if I do:

```
echo (ABC);
```

in the callback file, I **will** get the correct location value.

Comment: Is callback.php loading config.php at some point?  It needs to in order to access the constants defined in config.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$_POST['location']` variable, there's a string 'ABC'.

So if you do `echo($_POST['location']);`, you'll get `ABC`, not `some location`.

Try this one :

`$connect->setLocation(constant($_POST['location']));`

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to set the `a`-element's id property to your `ABC`-constant, you'd have to do it like this:

```
<a href="#" class="selectLocation" id="<?php echo ABC; ?>">
```

PHP constants are only resolved in PHP-code, not in HTML.

Besides that, encoding data in a DOM-element's ID seems somewhat convoluted to me. If I have to encode stuff in HTML elements, I prefer to use hidden `span`-tags or `hidden` elements if I'm inside a `form`. You can also try adding the following to your PHP script producing the HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    locationID = <?php echo ABC; ?>;
</script>
```

Assuming `locationID` is in global scope. Alternatively, you can provide some kind of `init()`-function in your JS file and call it via a snippet similar to the above.

Comment: No, I want to switch between php define values used in the rest of my code by clicking on a link. Therefor the id of the link is the define name and send by ajax to my function. I guess as $_POST is used to hold variables it cannot be used for constants

Comment: Well, but if you just want to receive the define's name, then everything seems fine to me? To quote you: _the $_POST['location']; will send ABC_ - and ABC is the name of the define. So where is the problem?

Comment: Apart from that: _I want to switch between php define values used in the rest of my code by clicking on a link_ sounds like you want to persist some kind of configuration somewhere, and change it via ajax requests. That is not possible with defines - they are only valid for the duration of one request (one PHP script invocation).